# Relationship between membership in a polynomial ideal, and derivable statements about solutions to the system of equations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ideals

Consider a set of polynomials $P$ in the polynomial ring of $n$ variables $\mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]$, and let $I$ be the ideal generated by the polynomials in $P$.

If for any zero (a solution) $x_1,...,x_n$ of the system of polynomials $P$, a polynomial $g$ satisfies $g(x_1,...,x_n)=0$, then:

1. Does this necessarily mean that for some power $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $g^k \in I$?
2. Are there some simple conditions under which $g$ is guaranteed to be in $I$?
3. Terminology-wise, is there a term for an ideal "expanded" (simplified?) $I \to I'$ such that if $g^k \in I$ then $g \in I'$?

---

Initially I thought that if I could derive that some polynomial $g(x_1,...,x_n)=0$ for any zero (solution) $x_1,...,x_n$ to system of polynomials $P$, then I could expect $g$ to be in the ideal generated by $P$.

However, as pointed out here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1173951/904055
An ideal has more information than a variety, as the multiplicity of the roots matter in the ideal, while only the set of zeros matters in the variety.

For example, consider the set of polynomials:
$$\{x_1 x_2,\ \ x_1^2 + x_2^2\}$$
We can see the first equation requires solutions to have at least one of $x_1$ or $x_2$ zero. Which when combined with the second equation, then requires the other variable to also be zero. So the only solution is $x_1 = x_2 = 0$.

Yet neither $x_1$ nor $x_1^2$ is in the ideal generated by those polynomials. However, $x_1^3$ is in the ideal, so in this case at least some power of the derived statement about the solutions is in the ideal.

So the first part of the question is whether I am at least guaranteed that this will always occur -- some power of any derivable statement about the solutions will always be in the ideal.

Second, are there some simple conditions under which it is safe to assume $g$ is in $I$?

In the example, the polynomials were square-free, but some linear combination of them were not. If instead the generators, as well as all linear combinations of them, were irreducible, then would it be valid to conclude $g$ is in $I$?

The case I am particularly interested in: a system of multilinear irreducible polynomials, where the set of monomials is distinct between every polynomial. In this extra constrained case, is it finally safe to conclude if a polynomial $g$ is zero for all solutions to the system of equations, that $g$ is in the ideal generated by the polynomials?

Comment: You'll be glad to know that the answer to these questions has been known for a very long time in the form of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz. It says that 1 is true, 2 occurs exactly when $I$ is radical, and the name for the process in 3 is taking the radical. This should be well-covered in any introductory book or course.

Comment: @KReiser The leads on terminology are very helpful, thank you! I am self learning (went down a rabbit hole trying to solve a system of polynomial equations), and not knowing the right terms to search for is painful.

Comment: Counter-example showing a system of multi-linear irreducible polynomials, where the set of monomials is distinct between every polynomial, yet the ideal is not radical https://mathoverflow.net/a/141215/176479